# Do I need a Dubai transit visa if I don't pass Immigration (same terminal)?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, dubai, emirates

I hold an Indian passport. I have a 7 hour 30 mins layover in Dubai airport.
Both my flights leave from the same terminal.

If I don't pass through Immigration, do I need a transit or any type of visa?

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for the answers! Extra information asked below: My flight is Emirates and it's a connecting flight. So I don't need to worry about luggage while in Dubai airport.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you do not. But I hope you have made arrangements for any hold luggage. The requirement for visas while in transit applies to a lot of travellers but at not very many locations (so far!).

Courtesy of [KLM](https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/visaform.htm):

> **TWOV (Transit Without Visa):**
>
> - Visa required, except for Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.
> - Visa is required for transit between Dubai International Airport (DXB) and Dubai Al Maktoum International (DWC).

Comment: For a single ticket and a 7:30 layover, Emirates should check the bags through.

Comment: We can't be sure unless the OP makes it clear, but it's a good guess. Almost everyone passing through DXB arrives, departs or both on Emirates. And if he's not changing terminals, it's most likely both. Further, he's not the only person who will read this post in future.